# Show menu items when authenticated in Orchard

Tags: orchardcms

On the main menu I have 5 items for an Orchard site.  Some of those menu items I only want to be visible after a user has logged in.

Any suggestions on how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to have two menus, one on the non authenticated layer and one on the authenticated layer, and have the authenticated items only on the menu being displayed on the authenticated layer. It introduces some replication but yeah, easy.

Answer (score 1):

You could enable `Content Item Permissions` and make your MenuItem Content Types `Securable` in their Content Definition. That way you can select exactly which roles are able to see each link.

1. Enable the `Content Item Permissions` feature
2. Check `Securable` and `Securable Content Items` in the Content Defintion of the Content Type you want to secure
3. Attach the `Content Permissions` Part to the Content Type you want to secure
4. Now you can set global permissions for the Content Type in the `Content Permissions` Part settings or override them on individual Content Items by checking or unchecking the appropriate boxes for every Role.

Comment: OK.  I can't seem to get this method to work.  "Content Item Permissions" is enabled.  I then went to "Content Definition" found the "Menu" and checked "Securable" and "Securable Content Items" and hit "Save".  However, the menu behaves the same if I'm logged in or not logged in.  Is there something else I'm missing?

Comment: @cgreathouse I forgot that you also have to attach the `Content Permissions` Part to the Content Types you want to secure. Then you can go to the Menu and you should see a bunch of checkboxes that you can check for each Role.

Comment: Hmmm, I must still be missing something.  I added the "Content_Permissions" part to the menu type.  I then unchecked everything.    The menu items are still visible and I can click on them and go to the page.  Is there something else that needs to be done?

Comment: Did you add it to the `Menu` type or the `MenuItem` type? You have to add the permissions to `Custom Link`, `Content Menu Item` etc.