# How to show or hide menu items based on the roles in Orchard Core 1.6.0?

Tags: orchardcms, orchardcms-1.6, orchard-modules, orchardcore

I am having 2 content items linked to 2 menu items in an Orchard Core menu.

I added a new role and set permission to only a specific content item, and removed the view permission of other content item.

Still both the content items are shown in the menu.

Any suggestions on how to show or hide menu items based on the roles in Orchard Core 1.6.0?

I tried enabling the securable option in the menu content type definition as per another post in StackOverflow.

[Show menu items when authenticated in Orchard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45766474/show-menu-items-when-authenticated-in-orchard)